# Determine $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb Z}^i(A,B)$ using projective resolutions

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors

I know that there are many resources (such as Chap. 17.1 Dummit & Foote, in particular pg. 786 Example 1; and Lemma 3.3.1 in Weibel) that calculate $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb Z}^i(A,B)$ for $i \geq 2$ using injective resolutions. I am wondering if there's a nice way to calculate $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb Z}^i(A,B)$ using projective resolutions instead.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. The ring of integers is hereditary so the functors in you post are always zero!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff yes I know that they are all zero; but I only know that because it was proved in the two textbooks I mentioned via "injectivity" related concepts. For example, in Dummit & Foote, they did it by finding an injective resolution of $B$, and then applying $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(A, -)$, and finding the cohomology group at position $i$ of the resulting cochain complex. My question is asking is there a proof of this except using some projective resolution of $A$ instead?

Comment: Sure: every abelian group $A$ has a projective resolution $0 \to P_1 \to P_0$.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri could you write this comment up as an answer? I'm a newbie to homological algebra, so I'd appreciate if you could explain this a bit.

Comment: In general, $\mathrm{Ext}^*_R(A,B)$ may be computed via an injective resolution for $B$, a projective resolution for $A$, or both at the same time. This can be seen using the theory of double complexes.

Answer (score 2):

Because every subgroup of a free abelian group is free, every abelian group has a free (hence projective) resolution of the form $0 \to P_1 \to P_0$. So $\textrm{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^i(A,B)=0$ when $i \geq 2$.

Comment: Any reason why the books did it using injective resolutions instead if it is so easy to do it using projective resolutions?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe to provide some experience with injective modules and resolutions? Injective modules are likely to be less familiar than free or projective modules.